# get playing wav audio level as output

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

I want to make a speaking mouth which moves or emits light or something when a playing wav file emits sound. So I need to detect when a wav file is speaking or when it is in a silence between words. Currently I'm using a pygame script that I have found

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("my_sentence.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue
```

I guess I could make some checking at the while loop to look the sounds output level, or something like that, and then send it to one of the gpio outputs. But I don't know how to achieve that.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: To me this seems like a question for the Raspberry Pi SE...I don't know why it was migrated.

Comment: If I understand the "music.get_busy() == True" while clause, it will be executed when the .wav file is playing. So you would put your motor commands in the while loop...right...or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @NULL for the answer. `music.get_busy() == True` will be true all the time, since the sound starts till the end. But I want to detect silences between words, I don't want to be the mouth moving authomatically all the time. I want to stop moving while the sentence is in silence.

Comment: I see. hmm....I'll think about it.

Comment: It can be done easily with circuit rather than parsing audio. are you only looking for software solution?

Comment: @user641719 i'm opened to anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to inspect the WAV file to work out when the voice is present. The simplest way to do this is look for loud and quiet periods. Because sound works with waves, when it's quiet the values in the wave file won't change very much, and when it's loud they'll be changing a lot.

One way of estimating loudness is the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance). As you can see the the article, this can be defined as `E[(X - mu)^2]`, which could be written `average((X - average(X))^2)`. Here, X is the value of the signal at a given point (the values stored in the WAV file, called `sample` in the code). If it's changing a lot, the variance will be large.

This would let you calculate the loudness of an entire file. However, you want to track how loud the file is at any given time, which means you need a form of [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average). An easy way to get this is with a [first-order low-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Simple_infinite_impulse_response_filter).

I haven't tested the code below so it's extremely unlikely to work, but it should get you started. It loads the WAV file, uses low-pass filters to track the mean and variance, and works out when the variance goes above and below a certain threshold. Then, while playing the WAV file it keeps track of the time since it started playing, and prints out whether the WAV file is loud or quiet.

Here's what you might still need to do:

- Fix all my deliberate mistakes in the code
- Add something useful to react to the loud/quiet changes
- Change the threshold and reaction_time to get good results with your audio
- Add some [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#In_engineering) (a variable threshold) to stop the light flickering

I hope this helps!

```
import wave
import struct
import time

def get_loud_times(wav_path, threshold=10000, time_constant=0.1):
    '''Work out which parts of a WAV file are loud.
        - threshold: the variance threshold that is considered loud
        - time_constant: the approximate reaction time in seconds'''

    wav = wave.open(wav_path, 'r')
    length = wav.getnframes()
    samplerate = wav.getframerate()

    assert wav.getnchannels() == 1, 'wav must be mono'
    assert wav.getsampwidth() == 2, 'wav must be 16-bit'

    # Our result will be a list of (time, is_loud) giving the times when
    # when the audio switches from loud to quiet and back.
    is_loud = False
    result = [(0., is_loud)]

    # The following values track the mean and variance of the signal.
    # When the variance is large, the audio is loud.
    mean = 0
    variance = 0

    # If alpha is small, mean and variance change slower but are less noisy.
    alpha = 1 / (time_constant * float(sample_rate))

    for i in range(length):
        sample_time = float(i) / samplerate
        sample = struct.unpack('<h', wav.readframes(1))

        # mean is the average value of sample
        mean = (1-alpha) * mean + alpha * sample

        # variance is the average value of (sample - mean) ** 2
        variance = (1-alpha) * variance + alpha * (sample - mean) ** 2

        # check if we're loud, and record the time if this changes
        new_is_loud = variance > threshold
        if is_loud != new_is_loud:
            result.append((sample_time, new_is_loud))
        is_loud = new_is_loud

    return result

def play_sentence(wav_path):
    loud_times = get_loud_times(wav_path)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(wav_path)

    start_time = time.time()
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

    for (t, is_loud) in loud_times:
        # wait until the time described by this entry
        sleep_time = start_time + t - time.time()
        if sleep_time > 0:
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

        # do whatever
        print 'loud' if is_loud else 'quiet'
```

Comment: your answer looks very good, I will read it again and try the code the following days. Thanks! ;)

Comment: I've made it community wiki so hopefully that means you can edit it with any fixes you find. Good luck!

Comment: sample_rate not defined, I get the sample as a tuple and can't multiply. Any updated code?