# Python & Audio Visualization

Tags: python-3.x, audio, pygame, pyaudio

I am working on a pet project for rendering data output in Python from audio. I have seen plenty of examples of processing WAV files (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571955/get-playing-wav-audio-level-as-output) StackOverflow question/answer).

My issues is that I want to process either WAV or MP3 the same way but also in a more "universal" way (such as not having to worry about sample sizing for unpacking)?

The overall goal of the project is simple:

1. Read the audio file (regardless of format)
2. Get a list of the audio levels
3. Play the sound
4. Move a line (or progress bar) up-and-down real time based on the "volume" as the sound plays
5. Evolve that into something a bit more visually appealing

[PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/)'s mixer works great for throwing any file I want at it, but I don't see a way to get file analysis from the data. The WAV files I have also don't work in the aforementioned StackOverflow post.

Converting on-the-fly all the time wouldn't give me the responsiveness I want and I want to avoid having to process every file I want to throw at this thing to force it into mono, etc.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571955/get-playing-wav-audio-level-as-output) is an old post. [`pygame.mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) and [`pygame.mixer.music.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load) both work with wav and mp3. Did you try it?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I must have missed the docs on `pygame.mixer.Sound` I'll have to try that and come back. I'm just going to have to dig to try and figure out where the analysis library stuff is.

Answer (score 0):

In the trend I've been having lately, I found something after asking a question.

I found the exact library I needed to take the complexity out: [librosa](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/index.html). There's also a great intro tutorial here: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-a-music-visualizer-7fad401f5a69 - I recommend looking here for people looking to start that don't want to worry too much about the math/physics just yet.